# Is Doubly link list OR BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, doubly-linked-list

Given a node with the following structure

```c
class Node {
int data,
Node* P1,
Node* p2;
}
```

We need to determine, if the node represents a Circular Doubly Link List OR a Binary Tree.
In my opinion We need to start traversing the given node in one direction

```c
node = givenNode;
while(node->P1 != null && node->P1 != givenNode)
{
  node = node->p1
}

if(node == givenNode) // It means Circular DLL
else if(node == null)  // It means Tree
```

And it would take O(n) time to detect this.

Please suggest if there is any better approach than this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you could check if its a doubl-linked list or not with this piece of code:

```
node = givenNode;
if(givenNode->P1 == null || givenNode->P2 == null)
 // It can not be double link list (circular)
else if(givenNode->p1->p2 == givenNode || givenNode->p2->p1 == givenNode)
{
//It is a double linked list
}
else
{
It is not a double linked list
}
```

And we have O(1) complexity

Comment: ... assuming there's more than one node in the list! (Otherwise it's unsolvable, or both answers are equally valid)

Comment: @george.zakaryan. Thanks for the quick answer, I have edited the answer to make it bit more accurate, because if we do not add the first check we might get a null pointer exception